# Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager not Installing

Tags: haxm

I'm having difficulties trying to install HAXM for my emulator in Windows 10. 
I am following the instruction guide provided in [Intel HAXM Instalation guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm).

I have installed the HAXM in Android SDK, and from the EXTRA folder, I am running the exe to actually install the HAXM.

I am getting below error in the installation wizard.
**"Intel hardware accelerated execution manager setup wizard ended prematurely"**

What I'm missing here.?

[Error Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJsI.png)

Comment: This is more suited for a site like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com). Are you running on an Intel or an AMD CPU?

Comment: Running on Intel Core (TM) i7, 64 bit .

Comment: Interesting. I had issues running HAXM a while ago, but I have a Ryzen 5 1500, and HAXM doesn't like running under AMD microcode apparently. Try migrating this to Super User, they have more expertise than we do on this subject.